# creating a frame to put pictures in it and saving back to database

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a mobile site and what I have to do is 1.create a picture frame 2.add to it pictures posted by users individually, then save each picture back to the database. Does anyone know how to go about this

Comment: Yes, a lot of us probably do, but unless you ask something specific, you're not likely to get an answer. "How do I do my work" is not a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield

If you need to have multiple images for user, you probably need similar model:

```
class ImageUpload(Model):
  user = ForeignKey(User)
  image = ImageField(..)
```